# Toogle key for AHK Script

Tags: autohotkey

Hi i'm having problens setting the toogle key and cant understand what i'm doing wrong.. and i just started using AutoHotKey.

If i keep key pressed all works fine but what i want to do is press "x" and run scipt then repress it and stop it

my code so far:

```html
#ifWinActive World of Warcraft
{
$1::
$^1::
$+1::
$!1::
Loop
{
if not GetKeyState("1", "P")
break
if GetKeyState("LCtrl", "P")
Send ^1
else if GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
Send +1
else if GetKeyState("LAlt", "P")
Send !1
else
Send 1
sleep 30
}
return
}
{
$2::
$^2::
$+2::
$!2::
Loop
{
if not GetKeyState("2", "P")
break
if GetKeyState("LCtrl", "P")
Send ^2
else if GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
Send +2
else if GetKeyState("LAlt", "P")
Send !2
else
Send 2
sleep 30
}
return
}
```

any help will be apreciated